# What does "Predicate Mismatch for View"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, soap

I am writing a iOS client for a an existing product that uses a legacy SOAP webservice. I got the proper URL to send my SOAP/XML messages too and even have some samples. However, none of them seem to work...

I always get a 404 error with the following error text "Predicate mismatch for View"

I am using an ASIFormDataRequest for the actual request and apending the data (SOAP XML in this case) via [someFormRequest appenData:myData].

I am flat out of ideas here and am wondering what, if anything I am doing wrong. Or should I ping one of the back end guys? Could this error be a result of something on the server side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error message spit out by the pyramid web framework when attempting to access a URL without supplying all of the required parameters. You definitely want to double check that the URL you are using has all of the required params (headers, query string options, request body, etc) and if you're convinced that what you are sending is correct then but your backend guys because it's definitely a miscommunication or a bug between the two of you.

Comment: You are correct... there was a typo in my XML.... It took me two days to find this.